# iOS - How do I wait for the code to finish before going to the next view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, interface-builder

I'm very new to coding and I'm stuck on what to do. I'm trying to get the user's geocoordinates from an address, use the coordinates to figure out some values then go to a different view controller where some code will be run to display the values that I figured out. The problem is it finds the users coordinates, Then goes to the next view controller where it doesn't have the calculated data needed to display it then tries to calculate the values needed from the first controller. How do I get this code to run in order?

My Code

```
@IBAction func BSearch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    getCoordinate(addressString: AdressInput) { coordinate, error in
        if error != nil {
            // Error
            return
        } else {
            user_lat = String(format: "%f", coordinate.latitude)
            user_long = String(format: "%f", coordinate.longitude) // Program gets this first
            self.getData(savedLat: user_lat, savedLong: user_long) // Lastly goes here
        }
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "TimeNavigation", sender: self) // Goes here second
}
```

The Function

```
func getCoordinate(addressString: String, completionHandler: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D, NSError?) -> Void ) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
               let location = placemark.location!
               completionHandler(location.coordinate, nil)
               return
            }
        }
        completionHandler(kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, error as NSError?)
    }
}
```

getData Function

```
func getData(savedLat: String, savedLong: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/lat/\(savedLat)/long/\(savedLong)") else{return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        var dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        let splits = dataAsString?.components(separatedBy: "|")

        let Counter:Int = splits?.count ?? 0

        for n in 0...(Counter-1){
            let splits2 = splits?[n].components(separatedBy: ",")
            for x in 0...9 {
                dataArray[n][x] = String(splits2?[x] ?? "nil")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it inside the closure because your performSegue execute before the closure result ... so write it inside the closure but on main thread

Update you getData function

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (_ success:Bool) -> Void
    func getData(savedLat:String,savedLong:String, completionBlock:@escaping CompletionHandler){

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/lat/\(savedLat)/long/\(savedLong)") else{return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {
            completionBlock(false)
            return
        }

        var dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

       let splits = dataAsString?.components(separatedBy: "|")
       let Counter:Int = splits?.count ?? 0

            for n in 0...(Counter-1){
               let splits2 = splits?[n].components(separatedBy: ",")
                    for x in 0...9 {
                       dataArray[n][x] = String(splits2?[x] ?? "nil")

                               }
                            completionBlock(true)
                         }

                  }.resume()
       }
```

And then your BSearch method

```
@IBAction func BSearch(_ sender: UIButton) {
   getCoordinate(addressString: "AdressInput") { coordinate, error in
      if error != nil {
         // Error
         return
      }
      else {

        user_lat = String(format: "%f", coordinate.latitude)
        user_long = String(format: "%f", coordinate.longitude) // Program gets this first
        self.getData(savedLat: "user_lat", savedLong: "user_long", completionBlock: {[weak self] success in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TimeNavigation", sender: self)
          }
                }) // Lastly goes here
              }
          }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this but unfortunately, it still decides to go to the segue before the .getData function. The getData function contains a URLSession if that makes any difference

Comment: I've posted the method. Sorry for the hassle, im just very new to all this

Answer (score -1):

You are calling your `performSegue` outside the scope of getCordinate function, which is why its getting called on click of the button and not waiting for the completion handler to finish.

Just move it inside and it will work fine.

```
@IBAction func BSearch(_ sender: UIButton) {
   getCoordinate(addressString: AdressInput) { coordinate, error in
            if error != nil {
              // Error
              return
            }
            else {

               user_lat = String(format: "%f", coordinate.latitude)
               user_long = String(format: "%f", coordinate.longitude) // Program gets this first
               self.getData(savedLat: user_lat, savedLong: user_long) // Lastly goes here
               DispatchQueue.main.async { //when performing UI related task, it should be on main thread
                 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TimeNavigation", sender: self) 
               }

              }
    }
}
```

Comment: it will give error ... as in closure you cant access performSegue without using self :)